# ASP.NET GridView - Cannot set the colour of the row during databind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

This is driving me NUTS!  It's something that I've done 100s of time with a Datagrid.  I'm now using a Gridview and I can't figure this out.

I've got this grid:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ID="gvSelect" CssClass="GridViewStyle"
        GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbldas" Text="blahblah"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

And during the RowDataBound I've tried:

```
Protected Sub gvSelect_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSelect.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey'")
    End If
End Sub
```

And it NEVER sets the row backcolor.. I've been successful in using:

```
gridrow.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
```

But doing the entire row? NOPE!  and it's driving me nuts.. does ANYONE have solution for me?

And just for fun I put this on the SAME page:

```
<asp:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ID="dgSelect" GridLines="None"
        ShowHeader="False" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbldas" Text="blahblah"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

And in the ItemDataBound I put:

```
If Not e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header And Not e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer Then
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey'")
End If
```

And it works as expected..  SO What am I doing wrong with the Gridview?

**UPDATE ************************

I thought I'd post the resulting HTML to show that any styles aren't affecting this.

Here's the gridview html:

```
<div class="AspNet-GridView" id="gvSelect"> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary=""> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td> 
                <span id="gvSelect_ctl02_lbldas">blahblah</span> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table> 
 </div>
```

And here's the resulting Datagrid HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="dgSelect" style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
<tr onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey'"> 
    <td> 
        <span id="dgSelect_ctl03_lbldas">blahblah</span> 
            </td> 
</tr>
 </table>
```

See.. the main difference is the  tag.  It never gets set in the gridview.. and I don't know why.. I've traced through it.. and the code gets run..  :S

Comment: i tried your code from the top and it works fine. did you check to see if there are style rules which set the bg color on the cells which would cover any bg color set on the row?

Comment: I removed all styles from the page..  and since the datagrid works fine, it doesn't make any sense..  could it be possible that I have bad version of the datagrid?  is there a service pack or hotfix for visual studio 2008 I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should actually be done during the RowCreatedEvent. Just tested the following code and it worked marvelously to highlight/unhighlight a row on mouseover.

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';")
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';")
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: Appending html output (NOTE: Works in both VB and C# with RowCreated - same output)

```
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ST_CD</th><th scope="col">ST_CD_ALPHA</th><th scope="col">ST_DESC</th>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>04</td><td>CA</td><td>CALIFORNIA                    </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>34</td><td>OH</td><td>OHIO                          </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>41</td><td>TN</td><td>TENNESSEE                     </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>42</td><td>TX</td><td>TEXAS                         </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>45</td><td>VA</td><td>VIRGINIA                      </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>46</td><td>WA</td><td>WASHINGTON                    </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>49</td><td>WY</td><td>WYOMING                       </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>14</td><td>IA</td><td>IOWA                          </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>24</td><td>MO</td><td>MISSOURI                      </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>40</td><td>SD</td><td>SOUTH DAKOTA                  </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>43</td><td>UT</td><td>UTAH                          </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>44</td><td>VT</td><td>VERMONT                       </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>47</td><td>WV</td><td>WEST VIRGINIA                 </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>48</td><td>WI</td><td>WISCONSIN                     </td>
    </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';">
      <td>54</td><td>AK</td><td>ALASKA                        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML side that I've got. I kept it simple. It's possible in your HTML side you have a css configuration that is interfering.

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ST_CD" HeaderText="ST_CD" SortExpression="ST_CD" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ST_CD_ALPHA" HeaderText="ST_CD_ALPHA" 
                SortExpression="ST_CD_ALPHA" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ST_DESC" HeaderText="ST_DESC" 
                SortExpression="ST_DESC" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebTestConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [ST_CD], [ST_CD_ALPHA], [ST_DESC] FROM [STATE_VALUES] WHERE ([ST_CD] LIKE '%' + @ST_CD + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="4" Name="ST_CD" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried it.. and it didn't work.. yet it works for my datagrid.. this is so frustrating..  there must be some other underlaying issue..  :S

Comment: @Dan: What framework are you using? I used that exact code in VS 2008 and it worked splendidly. I could test it in 2.0/3.0 though if that is what you're using.

Comment: I'm using 3.5.. and I checked my visual studio and it's version 9.0.30729.1  so.. it's got service pack 1...

Can you post the resulting HTML of the grid after you run the page?

Comment: @Dan: Posted the result using a table of some US states.

Comment: I wonder why yours is sooo much different than mine..  my div has <div class="AspNet-GridView" id="gvSelect"> while yours is just <div> and the ID is in the table name..  what is happening with mine?

Comment: @Dan: added the html side as well.

Comment: apparently I'm using CSS friendly control adapters.. : http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/gridview.aspx  hmmm.. I put that in for the asp:menu because it was slow in IE.. (go figure)..  hmmmm..

Comment: @Dan: Try removing the css class of the gridview itself.

Comment: I just commented out the gridview from the CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser file which I setup for the ASP:MENU...  ugh.. I hate when things like that happen..  If you never showed me your resulting HTML I would have never figured that out.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way:

```
Protected Sub gvwCompounds_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.CssClass = "rowstyle"
    End If
End Sub
```

and in example.css:

```
.rowstyle
{
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you're checking if it's a datarow twice.  I even tried your e.row.cssclass and when I look at the source of the rendered page it's still just: <tr>  not the expected <tr class="rowstyle">  :(

Comment: Thanks that was a mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: Yeah.. even still.. it's strange how it works in the DataGrid but not the GridView.. and they're both sitting there on the same page.  This makes me sad..

Comment: @Dan Are your arguments correct in the RowDataBound event handler? i.e. GridViewRowEventArgs

Comment: David,  Yep.  I edited my code to show it.  Perhaps it's a bug with this gridview control and VB.  I've only found code on the net in C# ..  I know it's not the RowDataBound because I can set the colour of a cell.. and make a cell highlight with a mouse over.. but the entire row doesn't work..  it never adds anything to the <tr>

Comment: @Dan try removing the CssClass="GridViewStyle" from the GridView and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it.. and it didn't work.. yet it works for my datagrid.. this is so frustrating..  there must be some other underlaying issue..  :S

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in IE6. I solved it with setting CssClass names of all cells in the gridview row. Here is the code:

```
private void grdvw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "rowHighlight(this,'lightOn');"); 
       e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "rowHighlight(this,'');");
    }
}

function rowHighlight(obj, nameOfTheClass) 
{
   cells = obj.getElementsByTagName("td");
   for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) 
   {
       cells[i].className = nameOfTheClass;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CSSFriendly Control Adapters for your GridViews?  They may not be rendering the attributes you add.